# Sharepoint Subsite users can access Parent site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, user-permissions

How would i go about blocking users from being able to access the Parent site from a sub-site
also in the ribbon where you can click the small folder and you get a tree view of the sites, i want the Parent site not to be visible for users which belong to the sub-site

I've tried giving the sub site separate permissions which doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you stop inherite permission in your sub site?

Comment: Yup, and still the user which is created can access the top site

Comment: Created sub site or top site? If top site what account is used to access the site? Administrator?

Comment: User is created in sub-site.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what kind of permission user has on top site.

Useally when user is created in sub site and granted with permissions he is automatically granted with min rights to be able to pass through the top site collection.

Try to find user in the readers group on top site level collection.

Check which rights he has and try to ungrant permissions...

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

look at powershell script that can map you all the autherizastions the user have , it can assist the problem solving